# Average time for Minecraft wheat to grow

Tags: binomial-distribution

The Minecraft wiki says ([here](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Crop_farming)) that, on average, under ideal conditions, after 31 minutes and 3.14 seconds, 80% of the crops in a wheat field should be fully grown.

I tried to prove that, but my result was 34 minutes and 55.55 seconds.
I will list my calculations and ask for your help to find mistakes.

Per tick (there are 20 ticks per second), 3 individual blocks out of $16*16*16=4096$ are randomly chosen and "ticked", so per tick the probability for a single block to be random-ticked is $\frac{3}{4096}$. Each time a wheat crop is random-ticked, the chance for it to increase its age by 1 is $\frac{1}{3}$. Combined, the chance for a wheat crop to increase its age is $\frac{3}{4096}*\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{4096}$ per tick. A wheat crop has 8 stages, so it must increase its age 7 times to be fully grown.

Now, with Excel, I used the cumulated binomial-distribution to find the number of ticks where P(X>=k) is closest to 0.8. The Excel formula I used is `=1-BINOM.VERT(7;n;1/4096;TRUE)` (I tried multiple values for `n`).

| n | k | p | P(X>=k) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41910 | 7 | 1/4096 | 0.799982 |
| 41911 | 7 | 1/4096 | 0.800003 |
| 41912 | 7 | 1/4096 | 0.800023 |

The result closest to 0.8 is the one with 41911 ticks. In minutes, this is $\frac{41911}{20*60}=34.93$.

Did I make mistakes?

Comment: When you write: *" so the probability is 3/4096"*: probability of **what**? Then, you write *"Combined, the chance for a wheat crop to increase its age is 3/4096 * 1/3 = 1/4096"*: What makes you think you can simply multiply here? Note that from what you describe, it's possible that up to 3 crops "grow" during a single tick. You don't account for this.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I edited this part to make clear what I mean.

If the multiplication is not allowed here, how would I do it correctly?